# Simulate counting over N sensors with java

Tags: java, multithreading, csv

I need to simulate in Java N sensors that send to me an obsvertation at random time. Where an observation contain more value like:

> timestamp - temperature - umiditiy - ...

When i receive an observation from anyone (the time of observation is random for all sensor) of the N sensors i need to call a rutine R that refresh a data structure (in common between all sensors) with some counting.

I need to syncronyze the R call, if i call R first time for call R second time i need R first time to finish his work.

All my observation are actually stored in a CSV file, one file for sensor. But i need to simulate a "online streaming".

How i can make that in Java? If i make N threads (one for sensor) that read his CSV file, i can't read the observation in right temporal order over all CSV.
For example, if i have this 2 csv:

```
Csv1: 
18:00 - low  - low 
19:00 - low  - high

Csv2 
18:03 - high - low
```

I need first to refresh my counting with obsvervation at time 18:00 in csv1, then with obsvervation at time 18:0 in csv2 and finally with observation at time 19:00 in csv2.

**EDIT1:** I have make a test with SynchronousQueue because I need to syncronyze my N thread, my problem is when one thread do something on counting structure other thread can't access to it.
I have find this example:

```
package threadTest;


import java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue;

public class SynchronousQueueTest 
{
    private SynchronousQueue sq = new SynchronousQueue(true);

    class PutThread implements Runnable 
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            for(int i=0; i <1000; i++)
            {
                try {
                System.out.println("PUT");
                //sq.put("A");
                sq.put("A");
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    class TakeThread implements Runnable 
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            for(int i=0; i <1000; i++)
            {
                try {
                System.out.println("TAKE");
                System.out.println(sq.take());
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Thread((new SynchronousQueueTest()).new PutThread()).start();
        new Thread((new SynchronousQueueTest()).new TakeThread()).start();
    }
}
```

But i have not the expected result. The output is only this:

```
PUT 
TAKE
```

But i'm expected 1000 PUT and 1000 TAKE alternate. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Ha. That sounds so much like what I do usually when preparing stock tick data for back test.

Normally you massage the CSV files to be at least internally time ordered. Then you can either read them and combine at beginning - or if you have multiple readers you need to put the data into a `PriorityQueue` based structure, say, `DelayQueue`. Have your simulation data structure wrap the actual data and implement `Delayed` interface so you know how much delay you need. This is all you need from reading side.

From publishing side, use just 1 thread and publish to the time you needed - then schedule the next round with delay like 1ms or so. That's usually enough.

From subscriber side, the subscriber is blind and just take the data as if it's from real.

BTW, if you are really doing back testing or so, you might want to write up your own time service class which can simulate a faster tick of the data.

Comment: I don't want to merge the file or to make one reader and one publisher because i work with big data. In this test i have one sensor for thread in the some computer, but in the future i need to parallelize the computing on more computer. With one thread for csv i want to simulate multiple computer.

Comment: Usually, 1 thread is enough to handle 1Gb/sec rate of messages. So unless you need exceptionally high message rate.

Comment: If you wanna simulate multiple computer, why not make an implementation of your customized distributed PriorityQueue?